# create a UIViewController's iPad version xib

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

In xcode4.2, I have a UiViewController bundled with a same name xib file. In the UiViewController, I have some IBOutlets as below connect to the xib.

```
    @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *topButton;
    @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *hotButton;
    @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *newButton;
    @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *starredButton;
```

Now, I want to create a iPad version xib file of the UIViewController, what shall I do? i.e. how to connect one IBOutlet to two version's xib. 
Any help will be appreciated! thanks advanced!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need two nibs with the appropriate naming

```
MyView~iphone.xib
MyView~ipad.xib
```

Then just make sure they both have the same file's owner and hook up the connections you want.

Answer (score 1):

Go to New File -> Choose User Interface from left hand side -> Select Empty -> Select ipad in device Family drop down.

Comment: i know this. I've modified the question.

Answer (score 0):

In xcode 4 we can't do that for a single xib,but we can create respective ipad versions all at once.Right click on target and click on duplicate.Then select "duplicate and transition to ipad".A new target and new set of xibs are created. This might help you.

Comment: I right click projetc target and choose duplicate, but no 'duplicate and transition to ipad' show to select, it just copy a target.

Comment: check this out http://s7.postimage.org/e7b7qo6ff/Screen_shot_2012_04_22_at_2_29_48_PM.png I think you have set ipad in the device section. go to Target ->Summary -> Device, then change the device to ipad from iphone, then duplicate the transition.

Comment: I got the ipad version target as you said, but it's not what i want, the ipad version target only adjust the original size by a '2x' button.